# Remove all skus woocommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin, sku

We have a site with over 1200 sku's that are wrong and we want to delete them all without affecting the products.

Is there a quicker way to do this via the db in phpmyadmin.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution. change post per page argument and post meta values for sku. (Not tested)

https://www.themelocation.com/how-to-updateadd-sku-of-all-products-in-woocommerce/

```
add_action( 'init', 'update_sku', 10, 1);

function update_sku( $sku ){

   $args = array(

           'post_type' => 'product',

          'posts_per_page' => -1

           );

   $i=0;

   $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

   if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

       while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

           $random_sku = mt_rand(100000, 999999);

           update_post_meta($loop->post->ID,'_sku','');

           $i++;
       endwhile;

   } else {
       echo __( 'No products found' );
   }
   wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: This solution sets a random value sku's for products. This isn't what's being asked for here. The question is how to go on about removing them from the database, not randomly setting values to all of them.

Comment: Here update_post_meta($loop->post->ID,'_sku',''); remove (update with empty) sku for products.

Comment: Can you confirm the actual sql query that I should try in phpadmin for this? @HarrySM

Comment: You can use like 
"UPDATE wp_postmeta SET 'meta_value'='' WHERE 'meta_key'='_sku' "
Please take a backup first before run query.

Comment: @HarrySM

Im not proficant in running sql queries.
Is this the actual cmd to run this to remove skus?

Comment: @GazzaC Yes, run query between double quote. but before that please take a backup of database or run this query in staging server first.

Comment: @HarrySM

I get this error
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'meta_value' <> '')' at line 1

Comment: Hi Guys,

Anyone know how to do this?